# How to force Django internationalization with languages not part of the official Django project?

Tags: django, localization, internationalization

I'm trying to activate Django translations in a language that is not yet part of the Django distribution. I'm more than happy to do Django translations in that language from now on, but since I need it now, I'd like to know if it's possible to activate a certain language even though the admin panel and Django messages have not yet been translated (since I don't need that).

I would like to not fiddle with the django installation, unless absolutely necessary.

If I set the `LANGUAGES` variable in `settings.py` to the following, for example:

```
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', _('English')),
    ('de', _('German')),
)
```

then it works fine and I can choose either German or English, with my own custom translations. If I do the following, however:

```
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', _('English')),
    ('af', _('Afrikaans')),
)
```

then the language in neither the session nor the cookie can be set to the `af` value, and it remains on `en`. I would think it would be possible to use `af` translations where available (as defined in my application locale files), then fall back to the `en` values otherwise? How does one do this?

Comment: @sixlettervariables: Why the vote to close? Has this been fixed?

Comment: Voted to close because the answer is "general reference" and right out of the documentation.

Comment: @sixlettervariables: While I agree that my self-answer was 'general reference', there might be a workaround (that doesn't require creating an entirely new translation) - which would be a better answer to the question itself. An app that handles something like that, for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/localization/#how-to-create-language-files):

> Django does not support localizing
>   your application into a locale for
>   which Django itself has not been
>   translated. In this case, it will
>   ignore your translation files. If you
>   were to try this and Django supported
>   it, you would inevitably see a mixture
>   of translated strings (from your
>   application) and English strings (from
>   Django itself). If you want to support
>   a locale for your application that is
>   not already part of Django, you’ll
>   need to make at least a minimal
>   translation of the Django core.

That's quite irritating though, I wouldn't mind having a mixture of English and translated strings. But, at least it can be done, even though it is with quite some trouble.